# Point it or Point it out

Tags: difference

> We need to rectify the errors before anybody **point it**.
>   We need to rectify the errors before anybody **point it out**.

In the above sentence, which is the better phrase to use: 'point it' or 'point it out'?

Comment: Given the definition of [point it out](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/point?q=point+out#point__107) I'm unsure what your question is.

Comment: @MattEllen it means *point (something) out* and thus in this context, *point (mistake) out*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To point something means to aim, like to point a weapon.

To point out means to put in evidence.

Comment: Good answer, but I can't vote this up as to specifically use either of his suggested options would be wrong.

Answer (score 8):

'We need to rectify the errors before anybody points them out.'

Comment: Or for a single error: We need to rectify the error before anybody points it out.

Comment: I would say this is the correct answer...

Answer (score 1):

The best way to say this would be:

"We need to rectify the errors before anybody notices them."

Answer (score 0):

It should be...

> We need to rectify the errors before anybody pointS them out (I guess it takes *s* and the errors are plural so *them*) .

That's because *[point (something) out](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/point?q=point%20out#point__107)* is a phrasal verb meaning drawing someone's attention toward. Here, it's *errors*.

Swan's book on English says that avoid *adverbial particles* if they are not needed *(You'll have to fill this form OVER You'll have to fill this form out)*. But then, here if we leave out the **out** from **point out**, it does not make any sense.

> We need to rectify the errors before anybody points (it).

Comment: @downvoter, comment please

Comment: I didn't downvote (this answer seems mostly fine to me), but I can make two comments: first, I'd probably use *them* rather than *it* to refer back to plural *errors*.  Second, I think *fix* would do in place of *rectify*, although I wouldn't insist on that change.

Comment: @snailplane But that won't be an answer then! It'll be the answer of the question *how do I prefer telling....(the sentence of OP)*. Here, there are two choices and the OP **wants** to know about them and not our opinion, neither the correct way to write it. And yes, I accept *them* and corrected.

Answer (score 0):

In American English, referring to a website, I would say one of the following.  I roughly ordered them in terms of the *real issue* that we would have to deal with rather than the fact that people will "point them out".

We need to **fix** the errors before it causes problems.
We need to **fix** the errors before people start complaining.
We need to **fix** the errors before people start submitting problem tickets.
We need to **fix** the errors before someone notices them.
We need to **fix** the errors before [someone | somebody | anyone | anybody] points them out.

Note: Points them out / Points it out are idiomatic phrases.

Comment: What do your brackets mean?